# So many users and their access

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms, workbench

I am developing a site which has around 46 departments and each dept has three Access types. Say `Dept Admin, Dept Lead, and Dept Agent`.

Site will use taxonomy terms `Confidential, Restricted, Private and Public`. Rules goes like this..

1. Dept Admin has access upto Confidential level records, Dept Lead->upto Restricted, Agents upto Private records.
2. dept records should be accessible by only that dept users and goes its content moderation
   I am planning to use taxonomy access control along with Workbench Moderation. But this requires me to set up 46 * 3 (138) roles for my site. I am a bit concerned that it might reach some php memory limit, not sure.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally went with duo Organic Group + OG Taxonomy permission modules